# I got a black screen every time Ubuntu boots, and I can't get to the GRUB menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia

When I was trying to install Ubuntu I got a black screen too, but back then, I press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit GRUB, and modified `quiet splash ---` to `quiet splash nomodeset` and successfully installed Ubuntu.

But everytime I boot Ubuntu, the only picture I can see is the login page, after that the only thing left in screen is black. I know Ubuntu booted successfully because when I pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and typed `reboot`, it worked, even I only got a black screen. So I guess nvidia is responsible for this.

I tried holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting Ubuntu, but I couldn't enter GRUB menu, I pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd> and only got GRUB command line, so how can I solve this?

Comment: The login screen use TTY 1 and the ubuntu session use TTY 2. You can switch to a command line interface (TTY 3) with "ctrl + alt + F3". If the issue is from the Nvidia driver you should be able fix it with commands. I can't help further because i don't use Nvidia.

Comment: @Jerare Thanks for comment, I saw command line with "ctrl + alt + F3", but only few seconds later it turned to black again.

Answer (score 4):

This black/blank screen is caused by `nouveau kernel drivers`.

> *Nouveau is the open-source graphics driver for NVIDIA graphics cards.*

They should be disabled at grub during boot or `tty` before you login.

## SOLUTION A

You need to update your grub with `nouveau.modeset=0` at the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="`

> You can do this by clicking **`e`** at boot time to edit grub or before you login by switching to `tty`.
>   To switch to tty click on `ctrl + alt + f3/f4`

1. In `tty` login and type

   ```
   nano /etc/default/grub
   ```

   to edit grub. Type `nouveau.modeset=0` after `quiet splash` to disable loading of nouveau kernel drivers.
2. Then type

   ```
   sudo bash -c "echo blacklist nouveau > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
   sudo bash -c "echo options nouveau modeset=0 >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
   ```
3. Confirm the content of the new modprobe config file:

   ```
   cat /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf
   ```

   > It should have an output similar to the one below:
   >
   > ```
   > blacklist nouveau 
   > options nouveau modeset=0
   > ```
4. Update *kernel initramfs*

   > Enter the following linux command to regenerate initramfs:
   >
   > ```
   > sudo update-initramfs -u
   > ```
5. Update Grub

   > Enter the following command to *update grub*

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
6. *Reboot* your computer.

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

## SOLUTION B

**To disable the Nouveau kernel driver:**

1. Remove the installed NVIDIA drivers:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge "nvidia*"
   sudo apt autoremove
   ```
2. Create a new file named `/etc/modprobe.d/disable-nouveau.conf` with the following lines:

   ```
   blacklist nouveau
   blacklist lbm-nouveau
   options nouveau modeset=0
   alias nouveau off
   alias lbm-nouveau off
   ```
3. Append this line to /etc/modprobe.d/nouveau-kms.conf:

   ```
   options nouveau modeset=0
   ```
4. Update the boot environment for your kernel:

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```
5. *Reboot* your computer and you should get a low resolution GUI which indicates that `nouveau graphics driver` is not being used.

## SOLUTION C

1. Cleanup all nvidia package ( remove all nvidia related packages).

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove nvidia* && sudo apt autoremove
   ```

   > If you get the following error it means that you never had an nvidia package installed and is ok:

   ```
   no matches found: nvidia*
   ```
2. Now install some required dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic
   ```
3. Black list nouveau driver (block and disable nouveau kernel driver)

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   ```
4. Append the follow lines to the blacklist.conf:

   ```
   blacklist nouveau 
   blacklist lbm-nouveau
   options nouveau modeset=0
   alias nouveau off
   alias lbm-nouveau off
   ```
5. Disable the Kernel nouveau by typing the following commands:

   ```
   echo options nouveau modeset=0 | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/nouveau-kms.conf
   ```
6. Update the boot environment for your kernel:

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```
7. Finally update and reboot:

   ```
   reboot
   ```

I hope this helps.

## References

1. [**How to disable nouveau driver link 1**](https://arstech.net/how-to-disable-nouveau-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-18-04/)
2. [**How to disable nouveau driver link 2**](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-nouveau-nvidia-driver-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)
3. [**How to remove nouveau kernel driver**](https://tutorials.technology/tutorials/85-How-to-remove-Nouveau-kernel-driver-Nvidia-install-error.html)
4. [**How to remove nouveau-kernel-driver-Nvidia-install**](https://tutorials.technology/tutorials/85-How-to-remove-Nouveau-kernel-driver-Nvidia-install-error.html)