# Destroyed sudo permissions, no access to grub due to nouveau kernal driver

Tags: grub2, sudo, data-recovery, root, nouveau

I managed to get myself into quite the corner.

I messed up permissions to `/usr/bin/` and all subdirectories, e.g. root is no longer owner of `/usr/bin/sudo`. As a result, I get the infamous [/usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452860/usr-bin-sudo-must-be-owned-by-uid-0-and-have-the-setuid-bit-set) error, which I found the above link to solve.

However, when I try to boot to either Recovery or an installation USB to re-install Ubuntu, I only get a black screen when trying to enter grub. From posts like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246482/i-got-a-black-screen-every-time-ubuntu-boots-and-i-cant-get-to-the-grub-menu) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280903/black-screen-instead-of-grub-and-then-login-screen-gui), I've gathered that grub is hidden in recent releases of Ubuntu. The issue now is that I cannot edit `/etc/default/grub` since I don't have sudo access...and we've come full circle.

EDIT:

I now believe that my blank screen when I press ESC at boot is because of `nouveau kernel drivers`, per [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246482/i-got-a-black-screen-every-time-ubuntu-boots-and-i-cant-get-to-the-grub-menu). But I cannot disable those at grub during boot without sudo access.

Comment: can you boot from a Live USB?

Comment: My understanding is that you have to enter grub to do that. Is there another way?

Comment: @ndeboldt USB boot is handled by your system firmware, not GRUB.  You should be able to boot to a liveusb (installer USB) to modify the installes system from the functional Live environment

Comment: there should be a keyboard key to show grub during boot. IIRC correctly you need to hold SHIFT during boot.

Comment: A single hit on ESC, as the BIOS/UEFI texts appear, should  make the grub menu show up. In the menu select recovery mode, use fsck and network options, then "drop to root prompt".

Comment: I've tried that - It's a repurposed Mac Pro, so UEFI not BIOS, but ESC should get me there. But I just get a blank screen, no grub. Maybe it's a separate issue?

I've read through a similar sounding issue here: 

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246482/i-got-a-black-screen-every-time-ubuntu-boots-and-i-cant-get-to-the-grub-menu

But all of the solutions require sudo access... which brings me back to square 0

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it, although I don't feel particularly elegant with my solution.

In the end, I disconnected my boot SSD and turned on the computer with the live USB I created connected. Grub came up and I was able to boot from the live USB. I elected to re-install Ubuntu from the USB, and reconnected my SSD. It was recognized and I was able to install to it. Problem solved!